I met an error when starting opnet modeler14.5, it seems a dll file miss
Error pop-up
The Opnet Modeler I installed and configured at first can run normally. Maybe after I added the op_model path (I'm not sure, maybe it was caused by other operations), this error message appeared when I started the software. How can I solve it?
the error message is To run product option (3dnv), shared object (op 3dnv.gui64.i0.ets.dll)must be in your model directories.
Cannot load product option (3dnw).
I checked the environment variables and found no problems. I hope I can solve the problem and launch it.
